# Rename SQL Server Name

Tags: sql-server

My SQL server name contains dashes,so its not working properly.I want to rename the existing server name without dashes.
       Is there anyway to rename sql server 2012 server name without dropping databases.

Thanks
Jamuna

Comment: you can use dashes(-) server name you don't need to change if you are bothering it use like that `[server--name].dbo.tblName`

Comment: In registry i'm using this server name,but its not working with square brackets.

Comment: @user1500633, what registry entry are you referring to?  Square bracket enclosures will be needed for linked server names that don't conform to the rules for regular identifiers (dashes not allowed), but that is the linked server name, not necessarily the actual server name.

Comment: I suppose he has some config inside the registry, @Dan Guzman.

Answer (score 2):

### Try below steps

> First collect the output of the current instance configuration. You
>   can get the instance name stored in the SQL Server metadata.
>
> Make sure you have backup of all the database if you are changing the
>   production server instance name.

```
sp_helpserver
select @@servername
You can change the instance name using below query. Default Instance

sp_dropserver 'old_name'
go
sp_addserver 'new_name','local'
go
Named Instance

sp_dropserver 'Server Name\old_Instance_name'
go
sp_addserver 'ServerName\New Instance Name','local'
go
Verify sql server instance configuration by running below queries

sp_helpserver
select @@servername
Restart the SQL Server Services.

net stop MSSQLServer
net start MSSQLServer
```

Answer (score -2):

**Using Management studio**
In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
Make sure that no one is using the database, and then set the database to single-user mode.
Expand Databases, right-click the database to rename, and then click Rename.
Enter the new database name, and then click OK.

Using Transact SQL

USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
Modify Name = Northwind ;
GO

Comment: I want to change the servername not database name.